# dockerfile: how use CMD or ENTRYPOINT from base image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I have several base docker images which are not owned by me (so I cannot modify them).  However, I'm creating new images from them with additional things installed.

What I can't figure out is how to tell dockerfile to copy the CMD (or ENTRYPOINT) of the base image.  Something like this:

```
FROM other:latest
RUN my-extra-install
CMD <use-the-CMD-from-base-image>
```

I don't think there's any direct syntax for the CMD command to do what I want. I'm wondering if there's a workaround.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If you left it blank in your new Dockerfile, it will inherit the one from the base image.

For example:

**base**

```
FROM ubuntu
CMD ["echo", "AAA"]
```

**layer1**

```
FROM base
```

If you build above images and run `layer1` you will get the following:

```
$ sudo docker run -it layer1
AAA
```

Comment: I thought I tried that and it failed.  But I just tried again and it certainly does work.

Comment: @Vor is ENTRYPOINT different?
What if both of my image and the base have an ENTRYPOINT?

Comment: @williamli if you omit ENTRYPOINT, it will be taken from the base image too

Answer (score 5):

@Vor is right. But in case

```
# Dockerfile
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /
```

and

```
# docker-entrypoint.sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh
set -e
exec "$@"
```

the default CMD from `nginx:stable-alpine` won't be executed in `exec "$@"`.

You must to write default nginx-alpine's `CMD` by yourself(!) in Dockerfile

```
# Dockerfile
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /
```

OR change your docker-entrypoint.sh

```
# docker-entrypoint.sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh
set -e
exec nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

Hope it helps